# You have attempted 5 times with wrong credential. Unable to login in in drupal

Tags: drupal

i am not able to login with the existing credential in drupal it is showing that you have attempted 5 times with wrong credential. Please Help. How to login with the existing credential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a table flood in drupal database. Just you need to truncate table by using below sql

```
TRUNCATE TABLE  flood.

Hope It will hep you. Happy coding.
```